# Will I go through an immigration office if I enter Romania by bus?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, romania, hungary

I'm a Brazilian citizen currently living in Czech Republic, in Pilsen.

If I take a bus to visit Romania for 90 days and enter the country by road will I have to go through an immigration office to cross the border?

Answer (score 3):

You should go through at least two, potentially colocated checks (an exit check in Hungary and an entry check in Romania). You might undergo additional checks if you transit through Serbia or Ukraine or if you encounter some random Czech, Slovak, or Austrian check.

Comment: Wrong, Hungarian-Romanian checkpoints are integrated due to the EU: same goes for Romanian-Bulgarian, Bulgarian-Greek and certain Slovene-Croatian and Hungarian-Croatian checkpoints. So it's just one check

Comment: @Coke Since when?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo No idea: it was only in 2014, when I started living alone, that I started travelling around crazy. Have bussed in Eastern Europe a fair deal now and know this to be a fact. Besides, as for the Hungarian-Romanian border, you can see it for yourself here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYyZu2ZY-t8 and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1yfICZGlBw

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo NOTE: I'm strictly referring to roads, not railways, where it's still done separately

Comment: @Coke That's a distinction without a difference, point is you're definitely getting checked and you will have two stamps/a SIS lookup/opportunity to be denied entry. And how is that “due to the EU”, especially if, as you just wrote, it does not apply to other checks on the same border?

Comment: @Relaxed From what I've been told, it is due to EU membership that most of these road checkpoints got integrated

Comment: @Coke I have slightly edited my answer…

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** 
Romania is not yet a Schengen member, so the border with Hungary is indeed supervised.